# jenkins can not connect by ip address

Tags: jenkins

I install jenkins on centOS 7 by `yum install jenkins`, and start jenkins `service jenkins start`.

Now I can access it by `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`, but I can't access it by ip (like: 192.168.1.77).

1. firewall is off
2. jeakins config is default
3. jenkins version: v2.64

`netstat -nltp` result: (I use port: 8088 now)

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9100          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23208/node_exporter 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23200/nginx: master 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9168          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23177/ruby          
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3053/dnsmasq        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1503/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1495/cupsd          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2856/master         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8060            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23200/nginx: master 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9121          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23224/redis_exporte 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9090          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23166/prometheus    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8899          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23258/unicorn maste 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9187          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23214/postgres_expo 
tcp6       0      0 ::1:9168                :::*                    LISTEN      23177/ruby          
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1503/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1495/cupsd          
tcp6       0      0 :::8088                 :::*                    LISTEN      886/java            
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      2856/master
```

`ifconfig` result:

```
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.99  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::a62:66ff:fe9e:fba3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:62:66:9e:fb:a3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 501018  bytes 502734098 (479.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 167889  bytes 16471815 (15.7 MiB)
        TX errors 14  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 11265076  bytes 8998994558 (8.3 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11265076  bytes 8998994558 (8.3 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:e3:8b:e1  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

with @StephenKing help , it works now:

The reason I think is that, when I execute `service iptables stop` , result is :

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl stop  iptables.service
Failed to stop iptables.service: Unit iptables.service not loaded.
```

so I think the firewall is off. In fact CentOS 7 use `firewall-cmd --state` result is `running`.

After running `iptables -F`, I do not know why, but it works now. This is not a good way!!!

Comment: did you tried with different port?

Comment: @user7294900 I try 8088 also fail

Comment: What does `netstat -nltp` output on that machine? Please add it to your question by editing it.

Comment: @StephenKing tks for comment, I add netstat result now

Comment: The IP address of the VM is `192.168.122.1`, right? Given the output, Jenkins listens to all interfaces ( `:::8080`), so if you access the correct IP, it should be reachable. Try also from within the VM. Verify the IP addresses using `ip addr`.

Comment: @StephenKing I add ifconfig result, I think my IP is 192.168.2.99, I access by 192.168.2.99:8088

Comment: Well, yes. That's also an IP of the machine. Does accessing http://192.168.2.99:8088 work?

Comment: @StephenKing Not work on port 8088.  The default port 8080 not work too

Comment: That's all on the same machine? No VMs involved? Are you sure that there's no firewalling involved?

Comment: I run on real machine, and `iptables` is off

Comment: @StephenKing I restart jenkins now and is works!!! I do not know why! Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

As seems from your `netstat` output, it's an IpV6 binding issue because Java process of Jenkins is listening to IpV6 only:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8088                 :::*                    LISTEN      886/java
```

And seems like your ISP doesn't get you out through IpV6 Address, that's why you can't access Jenkins. You can configure Java-Defaults in the sysconfig file, in my scenario I'm using CentOS 7, so I Modified this line in `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins`:

```
JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses=true"
```

Then `systemctl restart jenkins`, And now it's listening on IPv4:

```
[root@jenkins ~]# netstat -lntup | grep 8080
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1300/java
```

Thanks to [Link](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/Collaborator/server-running-on-IPv6-instead-of-IPv4/td-p/107306).

Answer (score 0):

Adding this here as it was the first hit on google.
I also had to configure the firewall.

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=http --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me on Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 9.1 (Plow)

firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp  a--permanent

firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=http --permanent

firewall-cmd --reload

Thank you @Balazs Gunics as you've saved a lot of my time.

Comment: add proper code blocks